# How can I change the website linked in my bio?

Tags: support, profile-page, network-profile

I have changed my blog's name and the blog specified in the bio section of my profile no longer exists.

How can I edit the website field specified in the Bio section of the profile?

Comment: Go to your profile and click "edit"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd edit your profile. There is a link just above the 'About Me' section:

[image: edit link]

which leads to a form where you can correct either the website field or your 'About Me' section:

[image: edit form]

Looking [at your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2779615/viji) you only are using the 'Website' field.

Answer (score 4):

In [your user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/234163/viji) there will be an edit link

[image]

and it will allow you to modify your profile including your website

[image]

Answer (score 3):

<sub>**Note:** Currently the other answers are obsolete, so adding the new answer.</sub>

---

There is a **Edit Profile** option is available in the [Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) tab of your user profile.

> [image: Edit Profile & Settings]

In that there is a section named "Web presence", you can add/update your website URL under that "Website link" textbox.

> [image: Website link]